# Library GMP not found in PHP

Tags: php

I'm on a hosted domain and I don't have access to the php.ini file.

When I run my PHP script I get the following:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function gmp_init()

which basically means I need the GMP library. phpinfo() shows that there is no such library installed.

Can I download a PHP version of such library and include it in my script?

Comment: PHP needs to be compiled with it. Had a word with the provider? Depending what you want to do then `bcmath` may have the functionality you require?